# Select the first subgroup in Pandas multi-index group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 level of indexes. For each level 1 Index, I want to select 1st Level 2 Index records.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
    'Year': ['2020','2020', '2019','2019','2019','2018', '2019','2018','2017'],'class':list('AISAAIASS'),
                  'val': randint(0, 10, 9)})
df

Person  Year class val
0   1   2020    A   8
1   1   2020    I   7
2   1   2019    S   6
3   2   2019    A   8
4   2   2019    A   1
5   2   2018    I   2
6   3   2019    A   0
7   3   2018    S   6
8   3   2017    S   8
```

I want 2020(Year) records for Person 1 (2 in no), 2019 records (2 in no.) for Person 2 and 2019 record ( 1 record) for Person 3.

I looked into lot of codes, still unable to get the answer. Is there a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) for first `MultiIndex` values and then filter by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                  'Year': ['2020','2020', '2019','2019','2019','2018', '2019','2018','2017'],
                  'class':list('AISAAIASS'),
                  'val': np.random.randint(0, 10, 9)}).set_index(['Person','Year'])
```

---

```
idx = df.index[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()]
df1 = df[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

Or get first index values by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) by first level:

```
df1 = df[df.index.isin(df.groupby(['Person']).head(1).index)]
```

---

```
print (df1)
            class  val
Person Year           
1      2020     A    0
       2020     I    8
2      2019     A    6
       2019     A    3
3      2019     A    7
```

Comment: beautifully done! learnt df.index.isin(index ..) today :)